# Regex for negative money format - 2decimal place & can go negative

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input and on input change, I change it to the money format.

```
<input type="number" class="currency" step="0.01">
```

like this:

```
$('input[type="number"].currency').on('input', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.match(/^-?\d+\.?\d{0,2}/);
});
```

However, as this gets triggered on every keypress, it doesn't let me write "-" as first character; so it erases it as soon as I click "-"

What kind of regex can I use for allowing that?

https://jsfiddle.net/4zv9wLr3/ - Here is a fiddle, try to write a negative number, it won't allow you to write.

Comment: Well your regex is requiring a minus symbol and at least one digit so the only way to achieve such an input is by pasting it. Your use of event listeners is the issue, not so much the regex.

Comment: This boils down to a UX issue. Don't mindlessly "fix" their issue, just warn the user that their input is wrong and prevent submission.

Comment: I want to be able to accept negative values too though - I can confirm that when i press "-", it goes into the input event. I think it's regex issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "number" input triggers the input event, the value was received blank.

```
$('input[type="number"].currency').on('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length !== 0) {
     this.value = this.value.match(/^-?\d+\.?\d{0,2}/);
  }
});
```

I added a guard like this and it worked.